# ¿Como valido si mi modelo viene null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Tengo una api en ASP.NET CORE 2.2 la cual tiene un `endpoint` de autenticacion que recibe un objeto `LoginModel` el cual envió desde postman, dentro del método de acción o del endpoint necesito validar si el objeto enviado es `null` o no para tirar un error, pero nunca entra en la validación.

Mi código:

```
[HttpPost, Route("login")]
    public IActionResult Login([FromBody] LoginModel model)
    {
        if (model.Equals(null))
        {
            return BadRequest(new { ErrorMessage = "Modelo invalido" });
        }

        // Lógica de login
    }
```

Desde postman le envié el request de diferentes formas para ver si entraba al `if` pero no pasa nada...

```
{
   "UserName":null,
   "Password": null
}
```

Probé así...

```
{ 

}
```

Y nada...

Answer (score 1):

Si envias una estructura json en el post al invocar el endpoint haras que modelbinding cree la instancia de esta de forma automatica

Para que el model llegue en null no envies nada, ni {} vacias ni nada solo un string vacio, de esa forma si deberia ser null el model

La validacion deberia ser

```
if (model == null){ ...
```

Igualmente lo que deberias validar son las propiedades

```
if (model.UserName == null || model.Password == null){ ...
```

ya que lo que usas realmente es la informacion que obtienes

Comment: La validación de model == null siempre será falsa ya que el modelbinding inicializa la clase. La manera correcta es con la segunda opción, validando las propiedades.